# Code has no errors, but it's not restoring the database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

This is my vb.net code to restore SQL Server database, I think the code does not contain a mistake, so when executing the code it does not appear to be wrong, but it does not restore the database.

Please help me to find the error. I searched a lot online but did not find any solution to the problem.

```vb
Sub restore_db()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HP;Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
    con.Open()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim strQuery As String

    Dim objdlg As New OpenFileDialog
    objdlg.FileName = "service_station"
    objdlg.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak"
    objdlg.ShowDialog()

    filename = objdlg.FileName

    strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE service_station set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
    strQuery = "RESTORE DATABASE service_station FROM disk='" & filename & "' WITH REPLACE,RECOVERY"
    strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE service_station SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated: "Query" instead of "Quary"

Comment: The only "Quary" you're executing is `ALTER DATABASE service_station SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. You're setting, and overwriting, the value of query on 3 different lines, and then executing the value of your "quary". At a guess, you should be concatenating the values of `strQuary`. And, to repeat, it's spelled "Qu**e**ry".

Comment: @Larnu Well, it's *spelled* query ;)

Comment: Why are you even thinking about restoring a database from vb.net? That seems like a terribly dangerous thing to do to me.  I would not want any outside application doing this to my database because I don't want to give admin rights to any outside application.

Comment: @HLGEM Applications can use use trusted connections, using the credentials of the user that opened the application. So the OP may not necessarily be granting to application access to do so (as the application itself actually has no permissions).

Comment: @Larnu, that is true, but as a data person, I can't trust the application will do things correctly always. I have seen far too many instances where they didn't in the last 20+ years.  Unless this is an application that is owned by the DBAs and is available only internally and no one else ever has access to use it,  I would not want it on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overwriting the query value:

```
strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE ..."
strQuery = "RESTORE DATABASE ..."
strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE ..."
```

Will result in the `strQuery` value only containing the last string. Instead you need to do something like this:

```vb
' First query
strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE ..."
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

' Second query
strQuery = "RESTORE DATABASE ..."
cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

' Third query
strQuery = "ALTER DATABASE ..."
cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Personally think it would be better to run it in a single batch. Otherwise, you might change the database to `SINGLE USER` and then, in that split second between one command and the next, something else then takes that single connection.

Comment: @Larnu It's using the same connection though, there's no disconnection and reconnection happening.

Comment: And don't drive future coworkers nuts with misspelled names. Make it strQuery.

Comment: @HLGEM Indeed, but people already pointed that out in the comments.

Comment: @DavidG true; I just never trust anything to ensure that it keeps a connection live between commands. A single batch just alleviates that (tiny) possibility. I'm not saying your answer was wrong  it's just personal preference. :)

Comment: Yeah but you didn't fix that in your code. And no one else mentioned why fixing it was important.

Comment: @HLGEM I'm not here to fix spelling, just the code. How OP wants to spell things is up to them. It's now been mentioned in half a dozen comments, if OP is reading this properly, I hope they will change it.

Comment: OP this is really a disaster waiting to happen...learn how to execute a few selects sequentially before you start trying to modify the entire database. Spelling is the least of your problems right now